# sql One-many and one-one relation between columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have no idea if the title matches what I am trying to achieve in the query given below. The example might not be great but it serves what I am trying to achieve. There are three results that I am trying to get as shown below.  Can this be done with a single query showing all the results in a better way?

TABLE:

```
name    surname gender
arjun   khadka  female
arjun   khadka  male
arjun   basnet  male
kumar   khadka  female
kumar   basnet  female
arjun   khadka  female
arjun   basnet  female
kumar   khadka  female
```

query:

```
    WITH cte
    AS (SELECT
      *,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name, surname) AS groupid1,
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name, surname, gender) AS groupid2
    FROM (SELECT
      name,
      surname,
      gender

   FROM name) x)
```

1. same person with duplicate gender as well as with non duplicate 
   gender

   ```
     SELECT
     name,
     surname,
     gender
   FROM CTE
   WHERE groupid1 IN (SELECT
     groupid1
   FROM cte
   GROUP BY groupid1,
            groupid2
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
   AND groupid1 IN (SELECT
     groupid1
   FROM cte
   GROUP BY groupid1,
            groupid2
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
   ```
2. same person with no duplicate gender at all

   ```
   SELECT
     *
   FROM cte
   WHERE groupid1 NOT IN (SELECT
     groupid1
   FROM cte
   GROUP BY groupid1,
            groupid2
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
   ```
3. same person having duplicate gender record only

   ```
   SELECT
     *
   FROM cte
   WHERE groupid1 IN (SELECT
     groupid1
   FROM cte
   GROUP BY groupid1,
            groupid2
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
   AND groupid1 NOT IN (SELECT
     groupid1
   FROM cte
   GROUP BY groupid1,
            groupid2
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
   ```

I modified what @uzi has provided, as solution as it has some flaws:

```
        select
           distinct  name, surname,personCount as count
            , personHasDupNUniqueGender = iif(min(allRowsCount) over (partition by personGroupId) = 1 and max (allRowsCount) over (partition by personGroupId) >1,1,0)
            , personHasUniqueGender = iif(max(allRowsCount) over (partition by personGroupId) = 1,1,0)
            , personHasAllDupGender = iif(personCount = allrowscount and personcount>1,1,0)
        from (
            select 
               *
                , personGroupId= DENSE_RANK() over (order by name, surname)
                , personCount = count(*) over (partition by name, surname)
                 , allRowsCount = count(*) over (partition by name, surname, gender)
            from 
                name
        ) t

        order by name, surname
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what the three conditions mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way. Query returns all rows with extra columns `condition_1, condition_2, condition_3`. Values of those columns either 1 or 0. 1 - matches condition

```
declare @t table (
    name varchar(100)
    , surname varchar(100)
    , gender varchar(100)
)
insert into @t values 
('arjun', 'khadka', 'female')
,('arjun', 'khadka', 'male')
,('arjun', 'basnet', 'male')
,('kumar', 'khadka', 'female')
,('kumar', 'basnet', 'female')
,('arjun', 'khadka', 'female')
,('arjun', 'basnet', 'female')
,('kumar', 'khadka', 'female')

select
    name, surname, gender
    , condition_1 = max(iif(cnt_1 = 1 and cnt_2 > 2, 1, 0)) over (partition by name, surname)
    , condition_2 = iif(cnt_2 - cnt_1 <= 1 and cnt_1 = 1, 1, 0)
    , condition_3 = iif(cnt_2 = cnt_1 and cnt_1 > 1, 1, 0)
from (
    select 
        *, cnt_1 = count(*) over (partition by name, surname, gender)
        , cnt_2 = count(*) over (partition by name, surname)
    from 
        @t
) t
order by name, surname
```

Output

```
name    surname   gender   condition_1   condition_2   condition_3
-------------------------------------------------------------------
arjun   basnet    female    0            1             0
arjun   basnet    male      0            1             0
arjun   khadka    female    1            0             0
arjun   khadka    female    1            0             0
arjun   khadka    male      1            0             0
kumar   basnet    female    0            1             0
kumar   khadka    female    0            0             1
kumar   khadka    female    0            0             1
```

Edit:

```
select
    name, surname, gender, cnt_1, cnt_2
    , condition_1 = max(iif(cnt_1 = 1 and cnt_2 > 2, 1, 0)) over (partition by name, surname)
    , condition_2 = iif(max(cnt_1) over (partition by name, surname) = 1, 1, 0)
    , condition_3 = iif(cnt_2 = cnt_1 and cnt_1 > 1, 1, 0)
from (
    select 
        *, cnt_1 = count(*) over (partition by name, surname, gender)
        , cnt_2 = count(*) over (partition by name, surname)
    from 
        @t
) t
order by name, surname
```

Comment: that is perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: there is a small problem though. if you add one more row "arjun, basnet ,Other" then condition_2 has problem.

Comment: I think we still have problem at condition 1. I came with a slightly different approach above.